# Add custom security check on Sharepoint 2010 document management

Tags: sharepoint, architecture, web-parts, crm, dynamics-crm-2011

I want, in a document management library, to be able to add another type of security based on Web services that I will call to check if user can see this document library.

How can I do that feature?

Answer (score 0):

Is your webservice call running as the user making the call?  If so, make sure the user has access to the doc library.

If the user does have permissions, and the webservice call is running as that user, the webservice should be able to access everything in the doc library that the user has permissions for.